# Magic 8 ball - text verification if almost the same?

Tags: php

I'm building a fun kind of 8 ball website in **PHP** where people ask questions and get a yes or no answer.

I'm looking to avoid the obvious mistakes like repeated questions... 
but I was hoping there was also a way of doing it to check if it almost the same.  For example, if someone typed the following questions one after the other into the program, it should be able to give the same answer:

```
Will I be rich this year?
Will I be rich?
Will I be rich
```

Is this possible?  I fault of the Eigen... thing, but not too familiar and these seem more complex than the usual.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Look into **[`similar_text`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php)**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

save it in database or in session and compare them

```
if (in_array($question, $_SESSION['questions'])){
    echo $_SESSION['answers'][array_search($question, $questions)];
}
$_SESSION['qustions'][] = $question;
$_SESSION['answers'][] = (rand(1,10) == 10) ? 'yes' : 'no';
```

You can also use [levenshtein](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) or [similar_text()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) function to calculate distances between questions